# Why is __cplusplus defined within extern "C"

Tags: c++, c, mpi

Within extern `"C" { }` the macro `__cplusplus` is still defined. When I want to include the C version of `mpi.h` in the header of my library which is dynamically load this will not work as `mpi.h` still finds `__cplusplus` and will still load like it was opened by C++.

`#undef __cplusplus` works with gcc. But I do not want to rely on this.

So how to write a C++ program that 
 - uses the C++ version of mpi and
 - is linked against a C-library that uses the C-Version of mpi (where `#include <mpi.h>` appears already in the header?

**Example code:**

library.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <mpi.h>

void library_do(MPI_Comm comm);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

program.cpp:

```
#include <library.h>

#include <mpi.h>

int main() {
  MPI::Init();
  // do some mpi C++ calls...  
  library_do(MPI::COMM_WORLD);
  MPI::Finalize();
}
```

In case somebody wants to play the example here the library.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

void library_do(MPI_Comm comm)
{
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    printf("MPI Rank: %d", rank);
}
```

And to compile everything I try with

```sh
mpicc -shared library.c -o lib.so
mpicxx program.cpp -l lib.so
```

Comment: `__cplusplus` is defined when you are compiling translation unit as C++ code. `extern "C" { }` does not make code inside compile as C

Comment: __cplusplus is a macro. It is defined and used by the preprocessor. The preprocessor has no idea about curly braces or C++ keywords. So whatever you expect of __cplusplus is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: The question is a prime example of an XY-Problem. You didn't include any code or error message - now you got *four correct answers* addressing your *question*, but probably not your *problem*. Please [edit] your question to make it more useful and to avoid that for any further questions.

Comment: *this will not work as `mpi.h` still finds `__cplusplus` and will still load like it was opened by C++.*  If `__cplusplus` was defined at compile time, and you didn't improperly define it yourself in C code, the library **is being opened by C++ code.**  `#undef __cplusplus` is [Easter egging](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/E/Easter-egging.html) - you are blindly changing things you don't understand trying to fix something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler outputs the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/map:60,
                 from /usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/mpicxx.h:38,
                 from /usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/mpi.h:2674,
                 from x1.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:72:3: error: template with C linkage
   template<typename _Iterator, typename _Container>
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:85:3: error: template with C linkage
   template<bool>
   ^
...
```

The mpi.h header detects that it's being compiled as C++ and so includes C++ specific features.  However templates (among other things) don't work with C linkage (i.e. if the header is within an `extern "C"` block).

Move the include above `extern "C"`:

```
#include <mpi.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void library_do(MPI_Comm comm);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: The problem still persists in the real world program which loads a cpp library that again depends on the C library using mpi. The error is
`libbla_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3MPI3Win4FreeEv`

Comment: Finally found the error for this too: I linked against the C version of MPI lib in the cpp library in cmake.

Answer (score 9):

`__cplusplus` will always be defined by the compiler if the compiler is a C++ compiler. `extern "C" {}` only gives you C linkage so the code inside plays nice with a C compiler.

Comment: Do you play nice with a C compiler?

Comment: @Bathsheba Only on sundays.

Comment: I don't think that it is important that it is a C++ _compiler_ but whether it is C++ _compiling_ (i.e. a `.cpp` file).

Answer (score 4):

The point of using

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

is to prevent the name mangling that C++ does. We are basically saying dont use the name mangling like a traditional C++ function call instead leave it undecorated.
This link could be useful [Name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

It is used to make C headers compatible with C++.
The flag `__cplusplus` is automatically defined in C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Because they are different things. `extern "C" {}` tells the compiler how to export symbols ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/73299)), whereas `__cplusplus` tells you that you can use C++ code so your library can use different code paths inbetween `#ifdef`s.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's defined. It's still a C++ compiler that compiled the code inside the `extern "C"` block. It doesn't stop treating the code as C++, only makes sure to use a C calling/naming convention.

If the header cannot be compiled by a C++ compiler, the only recourse is to create a **C** wrapper that exposes a C++ compatible API.

Comment: Can I wrap you up inside `extern "ST"` ?

Comment: @SombreroChicken - ST linkage results in UB.

Answer (score 1):

If you `#include <mpi.h>` from a C++ program, just don't put `extern "C"` around it. At least OpenMPI and Intel MPI do this for you in the header itself - if `__cplusplus` is defined.

You probably get into trouble because some MPI implementations still define the C++ interface in `mpi.h` that was deleted from the standard. This obviously breaks under `extern "C"`. For instance with OpenMP you can skip this by setting `OMPI_SKIP_MPICXX`. Then the double `extern "C"` works, but I still wouldn't recommend it.

Update: In case you can't modify the library header, just `#include <mpi.h>` before `#include <lib.h>`.

That said, you should not use the C++ bindings for MPI. They were **removed** from the standard more than 6 years ago, after being for 3 years...